# Aligning of Canvas using HTML5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am using HTML5. Can somebody please help me to align the canvas on the webpage. Initially I used div tag for placing an arrow.Now I need to get an ellipse after the arrow. I used canvas tag. But it didn't work. Can anyone guide me? I need to place multiple objects and so I used canvas. Thank you.
In div tag,

```
div id="container" align='left'
```

In canvas tag,

```
 canvas id="myCanvas" left="210" top="210" width="1000" height="200"
```

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a complete, minimal example of valid html.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about aligning -- meaning -- `"the ellipse after the arrow"`, and if by saying `"I need to place multiple objects and so I used canvas."` you mean that you would like the arrow and the ellipse to be ON the canvas, then you would need to manipulate the canvas using Javascript and its API.

You can try to start learning it from [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/canvas-from-scratch-pixel-manipulation/).

Comment: Thank you for your support..but it wasn't clear.What actually i need is that I have to draw a data flow diagram which is a sequence of arrows and ellipses and I need to place drop down objects in the ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

**How to draw ellipses connected by arrow lines**

Of course whatever you want to drag/draw into the ellipses is determined by your project requirements.

[image]

This function draws an ellipse given top, left and width.

A few notes:

- This is actually it’s an approximation of an ellipse—not a mathematical ellipse.
- The height is determined by the function.
- The function returns the endingX and centerY of the ellipse (useful when attaching connectors)

.

```
    function drawEllipse(x,cy,width) {
      // x=left, cy=vertical center of ellipse
      // note: just an approximation of an ellipse
      var height=width*0.40;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, cy);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        x+width/2*.05, cy-height,
        x+width-width/2*.05, cy-height,
        x+width, cy);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        x+width-width/2*.05, cy+height,
        x+width/2*.05, cy+height,
        x, cy);
      ctx.closePath();  
      ctx.stroke();
      return({x:x+width,y:cy});
    }
```

This function draws a connecting line with optional starting and ending arrowheads

```
    function drawConnector(startX,startY,endX,endY,hasStartArrow,hasEndArrow){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
        ctx.lineTo(endX,endY);
        ctx.stroke();
        if(hasStartArrow){
            var startRadians=Math.atan((endY-startY)/(endX-startX));
            startRadians+=((endX>startX)?-90:90)*Math.PI/180;
            drawArrow(startX,startY,startRadians);
        }
        if(hasEndArrow){
                var endRadians=Math.atan((endY-startY)/(endX-startX));
                endRadians+=((endX>startX)?90:-90)*Math.PI/180;
                drawArrow(endX,endY,endRadians);
        }
    }

    function drawArrow(x,y,radians){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.rotate(radians);
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(6,20);
        ctx.lineTo(-6,20);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/vnvhQ/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:15px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // holds the right/vertical-center point of the last ellipse or connector 
    var point;

    point=drawEllipse(20,50,100);
    point=drawConnector(point.x,point.y,250,100,true,true);
    point=drawEllipse(point.x,point.y,100);


    // x=left, cy=vertical center of ellipse
    function drawEllipse(x,cy,width) {
      // note: just an approximation of an ellipse
      var height=width*0.40;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, cy);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        x+width/2*.05, cy-height,
        x+width-width/2*.05, cy-height,
        x+width, cy);
      ctx.bezierCurveTo(
        x+width-width/2*.05, cy+height,
        x+width/2*.05, cy+height,
        x, cy);
      ctx.closePath();  
      ctx.stroke();
      return({x:x+width,y:cy});
    }

    function drawConnector(startX,startY,endX,endY,hasStartArrow,hasEndArrow){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
        ctx.lineTo(endX,endY);
        ctx.stroke();
        if(hasStartArrow){
            var startRadians=Math.atan((endY-startY)/(endX-startX));
            startRadians+=((endX>startX)?-90:90)*Math.PI/180;
            drawArrow(startX,startY,startRadians);
        }
        if(hasEndArrow){
                var endRadians=Math.atan((endY-startY)/(endX-startX));
                endRadians+=((endX>startX)?90:-90)*Math.PI/180;
                drawArrow(endX,endY,endRadians);
        }
        return({x:endX,y:endY});
    }

    function drawArrow(x,y,radians){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(x,y);
        ctx.rotate(radians);
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(6,20);
        ctx.lineTo(-6,20);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```